# Is the concept of "foreground process group" and "background process group(s)" applies when a session does not have a controlling terminal?

Tags: command-line

Based on my understanding, a session with a controlling terminal has a "foreground process group" and "background process group(s)".

But what if we have a session without a controlling terminal, is such a session still have a "foreground process group" and "background process group(s)"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "foreground" process group is generally defined for a terminal. Without a terminal, what is there to be in foreground or background of?

See for example, [POSIX on process groups](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html):

> A terminal may have a foreground process group associated with it. ...
>
> If a process is in the foreground process group of its controlling
>   terminal ...
>
> ...  all processes in the foreground process group for which the
>   terminal is the controlling terminal ...

Everything about a foreground process group is in the context of a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Process group are always managed by a main process (an SSH session by example). As soon as this main process is shutdown, all sub process including foreground and background task are killed as well.

There is some way to detach a process from where it is launched by example with `nohup`. This process is then just standalone and some tool need to be used if you need to bring back on foreground this kind of process, like the tool `reptyr`.

Source : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49106/how-to-recover-a-backgrounded-job-from-a-previous-shell